# Martingale representation theorem for Levy processes

Tags: stochastic-processes

Is there an equivalent of [martingale representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_representation_theorem) for [Levy processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process) in some form? I believe there is no such theorem in generality, but maybe there are some specific versions?

Comment: also posted to mo http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70981/

Comment: @Alice, yes, I haven't figured out why there are two sites yet...

Comment: I'm closing this question as the OP already received an answer at MathOverflow. @Grzenio: you should really consider reading our FAQ, or perhaps [searching Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/41/differences-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange). Saying that you don't know why there are two sites is like saying you don't know how to spell Connecticut: the information is all out there, the onus is on you to look/ask for it.

Comment: We general discourage simultaneous cross-posting to the two sites. In this case, I think the question is a good enough fit for MO that I closed this one here. In general, if you are not sure whether a question fits the mission statement of MathOverflow or Math.SE better, you should ask it here first.

Comment: @Willie, I read the FAQ but its rather vague. It says "Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level", which I understand includes research level, but then it says "you can get better response on our sister sites" for certain subjects (fair enough). I haven't seen anything about cross-posting. So to come back to your example, as far as I know there is only one way to spell Connecticut, but many ways to interpret your FAQ.

Comment: @Grzenio:  ... which implies that MathOverflow is for research-level questions **only**; questions of all level are welcome here. But you should also consult the FAQ at MathOverflow, as well as the meta thread I linked to (and other meta threads titled similarly) for the differences between the two sites.

Comment: @Grzenio: a propos cross posting, I know it is not in the FAQ (that's partly why I split into two comments instead of just one). Hence I explained it to you above in the comments why your question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out Theorem 61 in Protter's book about stochastic integration, but this covers only processes, that solve some affine SDE.